# Finding the pair of strings with most number of identical letters in an array

Tags: arrays, string, algorithm, performance, data-structures

Suppose I have an array of strings of different lengths.
It can be assumed that the strings have no repeating characters.
Using a brute-force algorithm, I can find the pair of strings that have the most number of identical letters (order does not matter - for example, "ABCDZFW" and "FBZ" have 3 identical letters) in n-squared time.
Is there a more efficient way to do this?
Attempt: I've tried to think of a solution using the trie data structure, but this won't work since a trie would only group together strings with similar prefixes.

Comment: What is the use case? Or is this homework?

Comment: what's the maximum length of your string?

Comment: Are the strings consist of only uppercase letter or what?

Comment: This isn't homework, and there isn't a specific use case. I was just curious about how to approach this sort of problem algorithmically. Yes, strings consist of only uppercase. The maximum length of the string is 26, since no character is repeated.

Comment: @VictorKwon Please check the answer again. I've corrected and extended the answer.

Comment: Thank you for the well-organized response!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I can find the pair of strings that have the most number of identical
>   letters (order does not matter - for example, "ABCDZFW" and "FBZ" have
>   3 identical letters) in n-squared time.

I think you can't as string comparison itself is `O(max(length(s1), length(s2)))` along with the `O(n^2)` loop for checking all pairs. However you can optimize the comparison of strings in some extent.

As you mentioned the strings don't have duplicates and I am assuming the strings consist of only uppercase letters according to your input. So, it turns into each string can be only 26 characters long.

For each string, we can use a bitmask. And for each character of a string, we can set the corresponding bit 1. For example:

```
ABCGH
11000111 (from LSB to MSB)
```

Thus, we have `n` bit-masks for `n` strings.

### Way #1

Now you can check all possible pairs of strings using `O(n^2)` loop and compare the string by ANDing two corresponding mask and check the number of set bits (hamming weight). Obviously this is an improvement of your version because the string comparison is optimized now - Only an AND operation between two 32 bit integer which is a `O(1)` operation.

For example for any two strings comparison will be:

```
ABCDG
ABCEF

X1 = mask(ABCDG) => 1001111
X2 = mask(ABCEF) => 0110111

X1 AND X2 => 0000111

hamming weight(0000111) => 3 // number of set bits
```

### Way #2

Now, one observation is the AND of same type bit is 1. So for every masks, we will try to maximize the [Hamming weight](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hamming_weight) (total number of set bits) of AND value of two string's masks as the string with most matched characters have same bit 1 and ANDing these two masks will make those bits 1.

Now build a Trie with all masks - every node of the trie will hold 0 or 1 based on the corresponding bit is set or not. Insert each mask from MSB ot LSB. Before inserting `i`th mask into Trie(already holding `i - 1` masks), we will query to try maximizing the Hamming weight of AND recusively by going to same bit's branch (to make the bit 1 in final AND variable) and **also to opposite bit's branch because in later levels you might get more set bits in this branch**.

Regarding this Trie part, for nice pictorial explanation, you can find a similar thread [here](https://threads-iiith.quora.com/Tutorial-on-Trie-and-example-problems) (this works with XOR).

Here in worst case, we will need to traverse many branches of trie for maximizing the hamming weight. And in worst case it will take around `6 * 10^6` operations (which will take ~1 sec in typical machine) and also we need additional space for building trie. But say the total number of strings is `10^5`, then for `O(n^2)` algorithms, it will take `10^10` operations which is too much - so the trie approach is still far better.

Let me know if you're having problem with implementation. Unfortunately I can able to help you with code only if you're a C/C++ or Java guy.

Thanks @JimMischel for pointing out a major flaw. I slightly misunderstood the statement first.

Comment: I don't think `xor` is the best way to do this. If you `and` the masks, you then have just those bits that are the same. Then you can use something like [this bithack](https://graphics.stanford.edu/~seander/bithacks.html#CountBitsSetParallel) to find the number of set bits, which you want to *maximize*. Either way you do it, though, it's still an O(n^2) algorithm.

Comment: @JimMischel No, it's not `O(n^2)`. Before inserting each element you query for minimizing XOR. If total number of strings is `n`, `n` insertion and query will take `O(N)` time asymptotically where `N = n * 32`. You can check the link above. And I can be wrong but can you mention a testcase where XOR won't work?

Comment: I stand corrected. I misunderstood your approach, and thought you were `xor`ing every mask with every other. I'm still a little unclear on how the trie helps you figure out that `01110` and `11111` have three bits in common. I guess I don't understand the xor query step. I'll examine your link more closely.

Comment: @JimMischel Thanks for pointing out. Yes you're right about the XOR. I misunderstood the statement first. I edited the answer now. Please check and let me know if you have any better idea.

Comment: Your second method is really just a binary tree with 26 levels. A query to determine the number of set bits in common involves an exhaustive tree search. Whereas the tree search might result in a somewhat smaller asymptotic time (I'm not completely convinced of that), in practice doing `(n^2)/2` AND operations will almost certainly be faster than `n` exhaustive tree searches.